# Загрузка файлов на сервер средствами PHP

Tags: php, upload

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
    // 1. check if photo is good (format/size in mb/size in px)
    if (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 30000000)){
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
            echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
        }
        else {                
            // 2. connect db
            $con = mysql_connect("localhost","aaa","bbb");
            if (!$con){
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
            }
            mysql_select_db("db", $con);
            // 3. get photo id from db "gallery"
            $send=mysql_query("INSERT INTO pictures (id, date_uploaded) VALUES (NULL, now())");
            $id=mysql_insert_id();
            // 4. create file id.
            $filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
            $file_ext = substr($filename, strripos($filename, '.')); // strip name
            $newfilename = $id . $file_ext;
            $path="temp/" . $newfilename;
            // temporary save it
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $path)){echo "success";}
            else {echo "fail";} // <-- error is here / ошибка здесь?
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "Problems with photo.";
    }
}
```

Не могу понять, почему не сохраняет файл...

Comment: Поставил минус за "Название для внимания".

Comment: Краще допоміг би

Comment: Чтобы вам помогли сформулируйте вопрос нормально с указанием ошибок, подробным описанием проблемы. Посмотрите поиск, даже по тегу [upload](http://hashcode.ru/questions/tagged/upload/) можно поискать свою проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если ошибок не выводит, скорее всего неверно выставлены права. Обязательно проверьте, выставлены ли права на запись файлов в указанную директорию.

Comment: А какие они должны быть?
Были 0755 заменил на 0775

Comment: Дуже дякую. Виправив. Ніколи б не здогадався без вас)))